# OpenCV - missing dlls

Tags: .net, opencv, dll, c++-cli

Using OpenCV 3.3.0

Using Visual Studio 2017, I try to run my code with no errors found.
Always say "The application cound not start correctly (0xc000007b)"(Translated).

Already have this dll files in debug folder:

- opencv_contrib_world330d.dll
- opencv_ffmpeg.dll
- opencv_ffmpeg330.dll
- opencv_ffmpeg330_64.dll
- opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll
- opencv_img_hash330d.dll
- opencv_world330.dll
- opencv_world330d.dll

Here is my code:

```
#pragma once
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\ocl.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ocl;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;
using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}

namespace ObjDetect_v1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

    Bitmap^ ConvertMatToBitmap(Mat matToConvert);

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Main
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Main : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Main(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Main()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox_Cam;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button_Start;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBoxHist;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBoxObj;


    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;


    protected:

    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->pictureBox_Cam = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->button_Start = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->pictureBoxHist = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->pictureBoxObj = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox_Cam))->BeginInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBoxHist))->BeginInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBoxObj))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox_Cam
            // 
            this->pictureBox_Cam->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->pictureBox_Cam->Name = L"pictureBox_Cam";
            this->pictureBox_Cam->Size = System::Drawing::Size(422, 288);
            this->pictureBox_Cam->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
            this->pictureBox_Cam->TabIndex = 0;
            this->pictureBox_Cam->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // button_Start
            // 
            this->button_Start->Location = System::Drawing::Point(359, 409);
            this->button_Start->Name = L"button_Start";
            this->button_Start->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button_Start->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button_Start->Text = L"Start";
            this->button_Start->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button_Start->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Main::button_Start_Click);
            // 
            // pictureBoxHist
            // 
            this->pictureBoxHist->Location = System::Drawing::Point(463, 12);
            this->pictureBoxHist->Name = L"pictureBoxHist";
            this->pictureBoxHist->Size = System::Drawing::Size(422, 288);
            this->pictureBoxHist->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
            this->pictureBoxHist->TabIndex = 2;
            this->pictureBoxHist->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBoxObj
            // 
            this->pictureBoxObj->Location = System::Drawing::Point(540, 324);
            this->pictureBoxObj->Name = L"pictureBoxObj";
            this->pictureBoxObj->Size = System::Drawing::Size(300, 163);
            this->pictureBoxObj->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
            this->pictureBoxObj->TabIndex = 3;
            this->pictureBoxObj->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Main
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(900, 508);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBoxObj);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBoxHist);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button_Start);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox_Cam);
            this->Name = L"Main";
            this->Text = L"Main";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox_Cam))->EndInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBoxHist))->EndInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBoxObj))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button_Start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
        if (!cv::ocl::haveOpenCL())
        {
            MessageBox::Show("OpenCL is not available...", "WARNING");
        }

        cv::ocl::Context context;
        if (!context.create(cv::ocl::Device::TYPE_GPU))
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Failed creating the context...", "WARNING");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i != context.ndevices(); i++)
        {
            cv::ocl::Device device = context.device(i);
            MessageBox::Show(gcnew System::String(device.name().c_str()), "WARNING");
        }

        cv::ocl::Device(context.device(0));

        // INIT
        VideoCapture videoCap;
        videoCap.open(0);

        Mat frame;
        Mat frame_gray;
        Mat ObjIM;
        Mat ObjDescript;
        Mat frameDescript;
        vector<KeyPoint> objKeys;
        vector<KeyPoint> frameKeys;
        FeatureDetector * detector = new SIFT();
        DescriptorExtractor * extractor = new SIFT();

        // OBJ TRATMENT
        OpenFileDialog ^ openFileDialog = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog->Filter = "PNG file |*.png";
        openFileDialog->Title = "Select a File to decrypt";
        if (openFileDialog->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(openFileDialog->FileName);
            ObjIM = imread(static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer()), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        }
        detector->detect(ObjIM, objKeys);
        extractor->compute(ObjIM, objKeys, ObjDescript);
        pictureBoxObj->Image = ConvertMatToBitmap(ObjIM);


        // FRAME TRATMENT
        videoCap.read(frame);
        pictureBox_Cam->Image = ConvertMatToBitmap(frame);
        cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);
        detector->detect(frame, frameKeys);
        extractor->compute(frame, frameKeys, frameDescript);

        // FLANN
        Mat Result;
        Mat Dist;
        int k = 2;
        flann::Index flannIndex(frameDescript, flann::LshIndexParams(12,20,2), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);
        flannIndex.knnSearch(ObjDescript, Result, Dist, k, flann::SearchParams());

        if (Dist.type() == CV_32F)
        {
            Mat tmp;
            Dist.convertTo(tmp, CV_32F);
            Dist = tmp;
        }

        float nndrRatio = 0.8;
        vector<Point2f> mpts_1;
        vector<Point2f> mpts_2;
        vector<int> indexes_1;
        vector<int> indexes_2;
        vector<uchar> outlier_mask;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ObjDescript.rows; i++)
        {
            if (Result.at<int>(i, 0) >= 0 &&
                Result.at<int>(i, 1) >= 0 &&
                Dist.at<float>(i, 0) <= nndrRatio * Dist.at<float>(i, 1))
            {
                mpts_1.push_back(objKeys.at(i).pt);
                indexes_1.push_back(i);
                mpts_2.push_back(frameKeys.at(Result.at<int>(i, 0)).pt);
                indexes_2.push_back(Result.at<int>(i,0));
            }
        }

        int nbMatches = 8;
        Mat FrameObj;
        if (mpts_1.size() >= nbMatches)
        {
            FrameObj = findHomography(mpts_1, mpts_2, RANSAC, 1, outlier_mask);
            //Rect(FrameObj,);
        }


        pictureBoxHist->Image = ConvertMatToBitmap(FrameObj);
    }
};
    Bitmap^ ConvertMatToBitmap(Mat matToConvert) {
        return gcnew Bitmap(matToConvert.cols, matToConvert.rows, 4 * matToConvert.rows, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, IntPtr(matToConvert.data));
    }
}
```

************** Update 1 **************

Result from Dependency Walker:

https://mega.nz/#!Ohd10LwD!eFyyhngvuwXTW7fkejc8NJToyXLx0b_Kw5IO3ycbY1Q

Comment: not sure, but this looks like c++/cli, not c++

Comment: Maybe you 're missing something like `opencv_features2d330d.dll`.

Comment: @tobi303 That's right! sorry

Comment: @DimChtz I don't have that file

Comment: @Samega7Cattac Since opencv 3.0 (maybe a bit earlier), features weren't free anymore. Most probably that's why you don't have this dll. That's why I switched back to opencv 2.4.11.

Comment: @DimChtz the features such as SIFT/SURF etc. are patent protected but can be used for academic use, just not for commercial use without a licence. They were factored out into the contrib/non_free library for openCV 3.X which needs to be downloaded as a separate thing. `features2d` still has quite a few algorithms included and is part of the standard openCV build. At this point there isn't enough information as to why the application fails to start. `xfeatures2d` though needs to be compiled from [`opencv_contrib`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)

Comment: @EdChum "patent protected but can be used for academic use, just not for commercial use without a licence" I didn't know that.

Comment: @DimChtz certainly SIFT/SURF have this licence restriction, I suspect the other ones like STAR and others I can't remember are the same. Personally I use Optical Flow and ORB as they are free. SURF patent is owned by Toyota I think along with some Swiss Uni whilst SIFT is American. It's a bit naff I think that these algorithmns are pushed about for study but you can't actually use them commercially, the licencing fees are extortionate

Comment: @EdChum I already have opencv contrib modules

Comment: @EdChum "patent protected but can be used for academic use, just not for commercial use without a licence" I didn't know that too. Good to know

Comment: Well then you need to determine what other dll dependencies you have then, it's possible ffmpeg or the hash dll has some other dll dependencies. You can use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find this out, drop each dll into the window, make a note of the dll requirements and then see if you can spot what is missing.

Comment: I can't remember which are non-free from the list: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/xfeatures2d but SURF/SIFT are definitely patented, http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/ I'm not sure about the others as some are experimental such as LUCID and Daisy so they maybe fine but BRIEF was originally under `features2d` and then moved so I suspect this is another non-free algorithm

Comment: @EdChum I will add the result file from dependecy walker to the question

Comment: I haven't parsed your entire dependency walker output but it seems to want the VS2015 dlls : MSVCP140D.DLL  , and VCRUNTIME140D.DLL are mentioned. How did get OpenCV did you download it or compile it from source?

Comment: @EdChum I downloaded the .exe from opencv github and extract to a folder, than I made the same with the extra modules. Used the cmake-gui to build the examples

Comment: But the dlls look like they were made using visual studio 2015 and you are running VS2017, it looks like it needs the MSVC runtime dlls for 2015 for release/debug in order for this to work. Can you try downloading,copying these to the folder and running again. Otherwise I'd just compile what you need from the source, which is what I do because I need the CUDA stuff tailored to what I want

Comment: @EdChum When I used cmake-gui, I selected "Visual Studio 15 2017". Sounds strange :$

Comment: but the dependency walker showed those dlls in the list, I could be wrong but personally I always build from source

Comment: @EdChum I run a example from `opencv\sources\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\xfeatures2D` using xFeature2D and the same issue occurred

Comment: @EdChum I don't think so... I made a project with face recognition and work with any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling the lib wrong!

1. Download Cmake from [official website](https://cmake.org/download/) and install it;
2. Go to [OpenCV Repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv);
3. Download the latest release and extract to a folder;
4. Go to [OpenCV-contrib Repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), download the latest release and
   extract it too;
5. Open Cmake-gui and set the `source code` to the folder of opencv;
6. Set `build the binaries` to a empty folder and it `configure`;
7. Search for `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE` and check it, also search for
   `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` and set the path to the modules folder
   inside of the opencv-contrib already extracted;
8. Hit `configure` again, then `generate` and finally `open project`;
9. Just hit to compile and all the files will be there.